# Column Filtering With Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

This is my dataframe
[image]

I want to filter the Market Cap column to only show data above 40,000,000 and delete the rest but Im getting an error each time I try the usual column filtring methods.

**TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'**

```
df = df.set_index('Symbol')
df = df.dropna(how='all').dropna()
df['MarketCap'] = df['MarketCap'].apply(lambda x: '{:.2f}'.format(x))
df["MarketCap"] <= 40000000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), then convert to `str`:

```
df = df.loc[df["MarketCap"] >= 40000000]
df['MarketCap'] = df['MarketCap'].apply(lambda x: '{:.2f}'.format(x))
```

Comment: it worked like magic...thank you very much. Had to correct <=  40000000 to  >=40000000

Comment: it's because by doing `'{:.2f}'.format(x)` you are implicitly converting data to `str`, and the comparison between `str` and `int` is not allowed.